# PowerDNS allow queries on a per domain basis

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, access-control-list, powerdns

I am replacing my BIND authoritative nameserver with PowerDNS w/ gmysql backend. I'd like to have my primary domain *example.com* and its associated hosts like *www.example.com* to be available to other internet nameservers. However, I want certain subdomains (such as *in.example.com* to resolve to internal IPs, and therefore I don't want them available to other nameservers. For example, *host.in.example.com* might point to 192.168.x.x.

I accomplished this before in BIND by specifying an ACL for the IP range of my internal network, then adding an *allow-query* line to the *in.example.com* zone.

Is this approach bogus? Is there some alternative to ACLs in PDNS? Do these internal names need to be delegated to another server? It would be convenient to have in one place for administration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently this is not supported in PowerDNS.

There are several patches that will add this functionality but all have limitations. The most promising I have found is: [PDNS ACLs](http://osdir.com/ml/network.dns.powerdns.devel/2003-03/msg00004.html)

Comment: Actually had seen this mailing list post, good stuff, thanks for reminding me to accept an answer here.